# How to set upload URL and file upload path in ng-file-upload (Lightweight Angular directive to upload files)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I am trying to implement jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/s8kc7wg0/112/
 of Drag and drop file upload  using angular js and 
it is working fine until I am using there URL path "  'http://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload"

I have used exactly the same code they have provided in the jsfiddle , I have understand that it will upload file in upload folder so i have created a folder name "upload" with 777 permission.

I am facing only issue with Controller url path section so i have given that code below.

`$scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    data: {
                      username: $scope.content,
                      file: file

                    }`

If you run this URL directly on the browser it will show you empty json data "{"size":0}"

I have searched for it in many website but not found any explanation about it.

**My Query** :

- what is the use of this URl
- how i can create this in my node js application.
- How i can set file upload path

  I have also checked there GitHub for details but no help
  https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The url is the server url that is accepting file upload requests. You need to setup a request listener on your node code and change the url to the endpoint that is listening to that request. What you see in the demo page is a sample Java Servlet accepting file upload requests on GAE instance just for the purpose of demoing.

Comment: Thank's @danial for guiding me into right direction, I have now solved this issue and understand how its works.